# xfce-panel needs to be restarted every time to show systray changes

Tags: xfce, 21.04, xfce-panel, xfce4-terminal

Every time to see changes of systray I need to open terminal and restart xfce4-panel(xfce on ubuntu 21.04).
is there a way not to restart xfce4-panel every time by terminal and see changes?
Tnx.

Comment: There isn't any setting in the panel to control refreshing the systray.  You might need to remove and reinstall the xfce4-panel.  If that doesn't fix it, you might have found a bug and file it as needed.  `ubuntu-bug xfce4-panel`

Comment: @Terrance I removed and reinstalled the xfce4-panel but it didn't work. as you told, it seems to be a bug. but after trying ubuntu-bug, I received the message "The problem cannot be reported: This does not seem to be an official Ubuntu package. ...."

Comment: Strange.  I can file a bug on mine if I do that, but that would be no help for your version since I use Xubuntu 20.04.  However, they may not do anything about it now since the support cycle for 21.04 is about to end in January of 2022.  Also, if you had installed the `xubuntu-desktop` then it might be official.  Sounds like you did it another way.  If that is the case, then you would have to file a bug separately with Xfce themselves.